# How to get global error message?

Tags: scala, playframework

I use a custom form validation in a controller:

```
verifying ("URL is already exist. Please choose another one.", 
  fields => models.DAUser.IfUrlValid(fields.email,fields.url))
```

In a view, I try to get the global error message by this:

```
@for(error <- data.globalErrors) {
  <p>@error.message</p>
}
```

But what I get is:

```
FormError(,URL is already exist. Please choose another one.,WrappedArray())
```

How to just get the message ("URL is already exist. Please choose another one.")?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `<p>@error.message.message</p>`?

Comment: Since you're repeating it twice, I thought you should know the correct grammar is "The URL already exists. Please choose another one.". @Peter [is correct](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.FormError).

Comment: @Peter, it works. I would think about that. DCKing, thank for correcting me.